# Bootstrap is not integrated with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I decided to try the bootstrap and it's been pain for me, it's not working.

what I did:

```
laravel new project
cd project
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install && npm run dev
```

Then in the welcome.blade.php I change the code to this snippet so I can test bootstrap:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Things I made sure they're correct:

1. The /resources/sass/app.scss has import
   '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';.
2. The includes in the HTML page

Screenshot of the files structure & configs might help:

[image: File structure]

[image: webpack.mix.js]

[image: app.scss]

Notes:

I am using Laravel 8.

Would appreciate any helps.

Comment: Did you actually run `npm run dev`? This should compile your assets to the `public` folder, I don't see any css/js there. Do you get any errors?

Comment: well, I did compile it, 'npm install && npm run dev' and I got a warning as I remember, but it was about updating something, now I re-did the compilation and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Actually I tried it again, I need to run npm run dev twice, did not know that

Comment: `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` what is this then ?

Comment: here's the issue, I found it after @brombeer response, somehow you need to run 'npm run dev' twice to compile the assets
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/finished-please-run-mix-again

Comment: Just to make it clear, in a "working" default environment you'd never have to run `npm run dev` twice to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two folders named `css` and `js` inside of the `public` folder.
[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLX87.png)

Then, download `compiled bootstrap`  from *https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/* and extract the downloaded file.

Then, browse the `css` folder which is inside the `bootstrap` and find the `bootstrap.min.css` file and find the `bootstrap.min.js` file from the `js` folder.

Then, copy those files(`bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap.min.js`) into the relevant `css` and `js` folders respectively under the `public` folder.

Then, rename the `bootstrap.min.css` file as `app.css` and rename `bootstrap.min.js` as `app.js`.[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRrbv.png)

Then, bootstrap is successfully working in your laravel app.
Best regards,